# Loading adsense with jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, wordpress

I am using a wordpress template and i am loading my adsense code using jquery. I am not using ajax coz it's illegal.

So here is my code:

Finding the first image inside the "posts holder" and place a div to load the adsense in there and under the first image.

```
$(".entry-content ").find("img:first").after("<div class='mobilead' style='width:300px; height:250px; float:left; margin:0 auto; margin-top:10px; margin-bottom:5px;'></div>");
var adm = $("#adsense").html();
$(".mobilead").html(adm);
```

and inside the body i have a div with id="adsense" and with display:none;

```
<div id="adsense" style="width:300px; height:250px; display:none;">
my adsense code goes here
</div>
```

The code works great on desktop devices but when i am testing it from mobile device i got white screen.

Any idea?

Comment: I'm not sure, but there could be a separate service offered by Google Adsense.  Based on that I catch a link [Ad code to use for mobile sites](https://support.google.com/adsense/answer/2447276?hl=en)